# How to filter in a written message in MYSQL column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to filter into an existing table. I want to print multiple selected data by filtering with HTML Select. I need SQL code.

*When saving data, I save it to the database using a comma (,)*

***My Code:***

```
SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE `title` LIKE '%WEB%'
```

**Table**:

[image]

**Data to Filter (HTML Select)**:

[image]

**Desired Result**:

[image]

Comment: Whenever you store serialised data into a database, Codd kills a puppy.

Comment: @CD001 What ?...

Comment: @AlexDeniz "Edgar Codd" is the inventor of the relational database. The comment above was about the fact that you should normalize the data in your `title` column by having a table of title records and `JOIN` it to your `account` table to allow multiple `titles` per `account` record without the need to parse a string to find if a record has a specific `title`. So the comment "Codd kills a puppy" is saying that you are "violating the spirit of RDB design".

Comment: Your data isn't atomic, it doesn't even hit [1st normal form](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) ... EF Codd laid down the foundations for RDBMS so the old DBA *"joke"* (about 3NF) goes: *"They key, the whole key and nothing but the key, so help me Codd"* ... but @daShier comment above says it far better ;) ... *Codd kills a puppy* is also a riff on the old *"Every time you ... God kills a kitten"* meme.

Comment: I understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an `OR` to your `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `account` 
WHERE (`title` LIKE '%WEB%') OR (`title` LIKE '%ADMOB%')
```